# Absolute value on the top of a fraction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

What is the answer to a question similar to this one, where the absolute value bars are only around the numerator of the fraction?

$$\frac{|2+4(2)|}{5-10}$$

Would the fraction be equal to $\frac{10}{-5}$ and would the answer just be $-2$?

Thanks

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: I appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the possible configurations:
 $$\frac{|1-2|}{1-2} = \frac{|-1|}{-1}=\frac{1}{-1} = -1$$

$$\frac{|1-2|}{|1-2|} = \frac{|-1|}{|-1|}=\frac{1}{1} = 1$$

$$\frac{1-2}{|1-2|} = \frac{-1}{|-1|}=\frac{-1}{1} = -1$$

$$\frac{1-2}{1-2} = \frac{-1}{-1}=\frac{-1}{-1} = 1$$

Answer (score 0):

You've done **right**! But, this is from where the concept comes from: $$| x| =\begin{cases} x & x >0 \\ 0 & x =  0 \\ -x & x < 0 \end{cases} $$

So, when you have: $|-1|$ you will simply write this as: $1$ as this obeys the third condition of the above general case. [as an example]

Once you understand this general case, it will be easy for you to move on in this topic.

Comment: You can reduce it to two cases by getting rid of the $x=0$ case and including it one of the others; i.e. $|x|=x$ if $x\geq 0$.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy - I appreciate that and I knew that point too. But, I just wanted this to be much clearer to the asker as I think, the asker is in the beginning stage for this.

Comment: Good point, well made.